# How to configure aspnet core json serialization

Tags: json, asp.net-core

I reported this issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48816 and the developer that responded posted code explaining how to manually deserialize the function argument. Asp is supposed to have an automated system for this however. So if my function definition looks like:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Session session)
{
...
```

then I am supposed to be able to just use session as a variable from that point without any special deserialization step. This suggests to me that there must be a way to set JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web) somewhere in a more global way so that it can consume the post data it is getting. Alternatively there might be a different way to serialize the post data differently on the client so that it does not get converted to camel case.

The main question is: what is the correct way to serialize and deserialize data objects for asp.net-core?

Comment: You should use `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Session session)`, and JSON will be deserialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Reproduce**

[image]

[image]

**Thanks for [Roar S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072498/roar-s)'s comment, use `[FromBody]`, it works.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I got the bug reopened for a second but the developer closed it again before I could add a link to this solution. Hopefully people find their way to the actual solution through their search engine. Thanks guys.